# Selecting a match across multiple rows sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, group-by, group-concat, having

Let's say I have a table named `food_prefs` of friends and their favorite food(s).

| id | name | favorite_foods |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Amy | Pizza |
| 2 | Bob | Pizza |
| 3 | Chad | Caviar |
| 4 | Dana | Pizza |
| 5 | Dana | Salad |

I understand how to get the names of everyone who likes pizza, but I'm unclear on how to select the people who only have `pizza` listed as their favorite food. That is, from the above table, I only want to select Amy and Bob.

Additionally, it would be great to have a solution that can also select names with multiple favorites (e.g. in another query select everyone who has `pizza and salad` as their favorite, which would). Finally, it could be useful if the `pizza and salad` query not only returned people who only liked both foods, but also people who only had one favorite that appears in that list (e.g. people who just like pizza or just like salad — everyone but chad in this example)

(I find the sqlite documentation not the most straightforward, so sorry if this is as a very straightforward question!)

Comment: It seems like using `group`ing by `name` and then selecting using `having group_concat(favorite_foods) = 'Pizza'` may work (as would `in ('Pizza', 'Pizza,Salad')`, but then it seems like would need to have the group concat options in every possible permutation listed, which doesn't seem great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right (as I read in your comment below your question) that for your requirement you need aggregation and the conditions in the `HAVING` clause.

For example, to get people who **only** have 'pizza' listed as their favorite food:

```
SELECT name 
FROM food_prefs 
GROUP BY name
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(favorite_foods) = 'Pizza';
```

But if you want to get people who **only** have 'pizza' and 'salad' listed as their favorite food, this:

```
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(favorite_foods) = 'Pizza,Salad'
```

may not work, because SQLite does not support an `ORDER BY` clause in the function `GROUP_CONCAT()`, so it is not guaranteed that it will return `'Pizza,Salad'` (it could also return `'Salad,Pizza'`).

In this case you need a more complex `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING SUM(favorite_foods IN ('Pizza', 'Salad')) = 2
   AND SUM(favorite_foods NOT IN ('Pizza', 'Salad')) = 0
```

or:

```
HAVING SUM(favorite_foods IN ('Pizza', 'Salad')) = 2
   AND COUNT(*) = 2
```

I assume that the combination of `name` and `favorite_foods` is unique.

For the case of people who have 'pizza' **and/or** 'salad' listed as their favorite food, but they also may have other foods listed, you need only a `WHERE` clause and not aggregation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name    
FROM food_prefs 
WHERE favorite_foods IN ('Pizza', 'Salad');
```

Comment: That all makes sense and thanks for confirming the ordering concern for the `GROUP_CONCAT`!

Also, it seems like we could extend the functionality of the `HAVING SUM` to be `>= 1` if we wanted to accommodate for having at least 1 of the foods as a favorite but none outside of the specified list (e.g. just liking salads or just liking pizza)

Comment: Second follow up: Is there any major performance difference between the `EXCEPT` solution I posted above and the `GROUP_CONCAT` + `HAVING SUM` solution?

Comment: @user12394023 yes you can modify the HAVING clause, which is quite flexible, for different requirements. Forthe solution with EXCEPT that you posted I have to say that I would not use a query that scans the table twice and then applies the operator EXCEPT on the results.

Comment: Having played around with it on the actual application with ~6000 items, it seems like the `EXCEPT` solution is quite a bit faster (somewhere in the range of 3x on my laptop)

Comment: @user12394023 faster to what? Your query returns all the names of the table with a favorite food in the list ('pizza', 'salad') and no other favorite food, but it could return people with only 'pizza' or only 'salad' as their favorite food. None of my queries does that.

Answer (score 1):

(OP here) `EXCEPT` seems to do the trick:

```
SELECT name
FROM food_prefs
WHERE favorite_foods in ('pizza', 'salad')
EXCEPT
SELECT name
FROM food_prefs
WHERE favorite_foods not in ('pizza', 'salad')
```

To my understanding, it selects all of the `name`s that have a favorite food in our list of options and then removes all `name`s that have favorites outside of that list (in the example above, `('pizza', 'salad')`).